# Python 3.5 - How can I make this code more efficient/shorter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I have a

```
list = [value, value, value, value, value, value, value, value, value]
```

where value takes on values: -1, 0 or 1.

```
if list[0] + list[1] + list[2] == 3:
    alternative1 = True
elif list[0] + list[1] + list[2] == -3:
    alternative2 = True
elif list[3] + list[4] + list[5] == 3:
    alternative1 = True
elif list[3] + list[4] + list[5] == -3:
    alternative2 = True
elif list[6] + list[7] + list[8] == 3:
    alternative1 = True
elif list[6] + list[7] + list[8] == -3:
    alternative2 = True
elif list[0] + list[3] + list[6] == 3:
    alternative1 = True
elif list[0] + list[3] + list[6] == -3:
    alternative2 = True
elif list[1] + list[4] + list[7] == 3:
    alternative1 = True
elif list[1] + list[4] + list[7] == -3:
    alternative2 = True
elif list[2] + list[5] + list[8] == 3:
    alternative1 = True
elif list[2] + list[5] + list[8] == -3:
    alternative2 = True
elif list[0] + list[4] + list[8] == 3:
    alternative1 = True
elif list[0] + list[4] + list[8] == -3:
    alternative2 = True
elif list[2] + list[4] + list[6] == 3:
    alternative1 = True
elif list[2] + list[4] + list[6] == -3:
    alternative2 = True
```

So how can I make this code more efficient/shorter? I suppose I could accomplish this with some kind of while-loop or something similar, but I can't get the list-placeholders to match.

Comment: This is columns, rows and diagonals, isn't it? Some kind of Tic-Tac-Toe checker?

Comment: `for index1, index2, index3 in [(0, 1, 2), ...]: if list[index1] + list[index2] + list[index3] == mul: ...`? And don't shadow `list`.

Comment: Yes, quite a similar problem actually. @Delgan

Comment: Thank, will try it. What do you mean don't shadow list? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Don't name things `list`, as that's the name of a built-in type.

Comment: Oh, ofc. Just made it in this example. :) Thanks, it worked perfectly. @jonrsharpe

Comment: If it is a 3x3 grid it might be easier to refactor to use a 2-d array (a list of lists in straight Python)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for code review of working code which is more fitting for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Some general advice:

- Code is often **much** more clear and easier to modify when your logic is in data instead of code. Build a data structure that maps situations to actions. Jon Bentley's *Programming Pearls* covers this in detail.
- You can use a dict as a 2-D array: `board={}` then `board[2,2]` where the keys are tuples.
- Having done that, you can then normalize patterns to handle patterns that are reflections or rotations of each other in the same way. (Not shown below.)

To make this more concrete, let us suppose this is standard tic-tac-toe and consider how to detect a win, which seems to be your goal for at least part of this code. We will use the 2-D array, with `1, 0, -1` meaning `X, empty, O` as you seem to be doing (though your particular coding might differ).

```
# List of winning combos.
win_runs = [
    ((0,0), (0,1), (0,2)), # ... rows
    ((0,0), (1,0), (2,0)), # ... columns
    ((2,0), (1,1), (0,2)), # ... diagonals
]

# Initialize empty board.
board = {(i,j): 0 for i in range(3) for j in range(3)}

# Set up a win in leftmost column.
board[0,0] = board[1,0] = board[2,0] = -1

# Check if anyone has a win.
for run in win_runs:
    values = {board[tup] for tup in run} # values is a set
    if len(values) == 1 and 0 not in values:
        print('{} wins'.format(values.pop()))
        break
else:  # executed only if for loop is exhausted
    print('no one wins yet')
```